# How to join tables on column name in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there any possible ways to reproduce this query

```
select table2.node_id as id, table2.client_id as clientId, table1.collection_id as collectionId from table1 inner join table2 on table2.primary_collection_id = table1.collection_id
```

in sequelize orm?

I defined `hasOne` and `belongsTo` relations and tried to do so:

```
return Models.FileModel.findAll({
    include: [
        { model: Models.NodeModel, required: true}
    ]
});
```

But I have incorrect `inner join` condition: 
`inner join table2 on table2.node_id = table1.collection_d`

Need to replace `table2.node_id` with `table2.primary_collection_id`

Comment: Pls include the code where you set up the relationship between the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sometimes need to be more attentive when reading docs. 
I was looking for `targetKey`

So I defined association

```
FileModel.belongsTo(NodeModel, {foreignKey: 'collection_id', targetKey: 'primary_collection_id'});
```

and it works for me